# I seem to have locked myself out of access to the webserver root on port 80

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, port

I'm running a VPS with ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4.

Well, what in fact has happened is that trying to access my site (`http://example.net`, say) I get the 403 error and the message that / is not available to me.

For several years I've been running this server happily, which includes wordpress.org, and a few educational services for my students.  Wordpress would normally run in the webserver root directory `/var/www/html` on port 80, and be accessed by the URL `http://example.net`.

Two days ago I installed the project management system openproject, which after installation ended up on port 80.  So my site `http://example.net` opened up openproject instead of wordpress.

I attempted to get round that by adding the line

```
Listen 8080
```

to the file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and edited the first line of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/openproject.conf` to the line

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

So now openproject can be opened with `http://example.net:8080`, which suits me fine.  But now port 80 is unavailable.  When I run `sudo apache2ctl -S` I find the following:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           localhost (/etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/20_repoman_svn_vhost.conf:1)
*:443                  example.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
*:8080                 example.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/openproject.conf:3)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
```

So clearly something's wrong, because I would expect the last line here to read something like:

```
*:80                 example.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf)
```

So for some reason apache2 is not serving up its root directory.  I've spent far longer than I should fiddling with this, but I can't work out what's wrong.  The file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` contains the lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName numbersandshapes.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
      AllowOverride All
      #  Require all granted 
    </Directory>

...and a few other things...

</VirtualHost>
```

and this file is not symlinked to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.  I can't remember whether it was or not originally.  I've got myself hopelessly confused and tangled in all the configuration files under `/etc/apache2`.

How can I get my wordpress (and other services running from the root directory) back again?

Comment: What was in the error log?

Comment: I checked the error logs and almost all the recent errors were due to my webdav setup:  

`[Sun Sep 11 10:51:14.262940 2016] [rewrite:error] [pid 30720] [client 140.159.2.234:29353] AH00670: Options FollowSymLin
ks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to c
ircumvent directory restrictions : /var/www/html/webdav`

But the directory /var/www/html/webdav doesn't exist... Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a vhost definition in this file:

```
/etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/20_repoman_svn_vhost.conf
```

that should also be told to listen on port 8080.

Comment: Well you're quite right!  What a thing to know - I'm *very* impressed.

Comment: Great, happy to help.